# Any file-descriptor changes in os.execvp() in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipe, exec, file-descriptor

I have a script, which works reasonably well under Python-2. It uses `os.pipe()` to create a pipe, and then passes the descriptor of the writing side of the pipe to a child process:

```py
    reader, writer = os.pipe()
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        # Child
        os.close(reader)
        os.execvp('command', ['command', '-o', '/dev/fd/%d' % writer])
    ...
```

Under Python-2 the above works, and the child writes to the specified file-descriptor -- allowing the parent to read it.

Under Python-3 the child complains about being unable to open the `/dev/fd/4` -- which means, the descriptor is not passed to the child for some reason. What would that reason be -- and is it possible to invoke `os.execvp` with the old, expected, behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a change to `os.execvp` but rather a change to `os.pipe`. Note that [the Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pipe) says "The new file descriptor is [non-inheritable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#fd-inheritance)", but [the Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.pipe) does not. As explained in that link, to make it work in Python 3, do `os.set_inheritable(writer, True)`. (And by the way, this means that your `os.close(reader)` is redundant, since it's not inheritable either, so you can remove that line.)

Comment: Amazing, thanks. I'm keeping the `os.close(reader)` so that things still work with Python-2.